# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 with dockers

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I am trying to build a docker-compose file for my Postgres which uses sequelize as ORM (https://sequelize.org/). Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"

services:

 web:
  build: 
    context : .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  image : testorganization
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  links:
   - db

 db:
  image: postgres
  expose:
    - 5432
  volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db
  environment:
    POSTGRES_HOST: db
    POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASS: admin
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8-alpine
LABEL description="Docker file for organizations app"
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/logs/
RUN mkdir -p /logs/
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/

ADD package.json /usr/src/package.json
RUN npm install --production

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Below is my connection string

```
this.sequelize =  new Sequelize( 'postgres','postgres','admin',{'host':'db', 'dialect': 'postgres',"define": { "createdAt": "createdat","updatedAt": "updatedat"}, 'operatorAliases': operatorsAliases} );
```

No matter what changes I do it always connects to 127.0.0.1:5432 and get the following error:

```
web_1  | Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
web_1  |     at connection.connect.err (/usr/src/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connectionmanager.js:170:24)
web_1  |     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/usr/src/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:191:14)
web_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
web_1  |     at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
web_1  |     at Socket.reportStreamError (/usr/src/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:72:10)
web_1  |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
web_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
web_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:66:8)
web_1  |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
web_1  |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

1. Tried keeping the domain `db` in the connection string, the same reference used in the docker-compose file
2. Kept all connections open the postgres.conf file.

What am I missing? Been stuck on this for some time now.
Thanks

Comment: This line `image : testorganization` needs to be removed.

Comment: Looks like Docker resolves the `db` DNS name to `localhost` because you are using the old `links` syntax inside your docker-compose file. I would recommend not using `links` anymore and instead defining a network inside your docker-compose file. You can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#networks) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres", "postgres", "admin", {
  host: "db",
  dialect: "postgres",
  pool: {
    max: 9,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log("Success!");
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**Dockerfile** - same as in the Question

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "",
    "pg": ""
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml (rewritten version)

Important: If you define both image & Dockerfile and build, image takes priority and it will not build using your dockerfile.

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context : .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - examplenetwork
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - examplenetwork
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASS=admin 

networks:
  examplenetwork: 

volumes:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal version of your Dockerfile / source to reproduce the error?

Comment: Please post the concrete error message. Can you share an example code to reproduce the error? Currently, it points to an issue in the code. Infrastructure wise the communication between the containers is working for me with the above docker-compose.yml

Comment: Edited with the error message. Posting the code will be too long hence posted the connection string. If i make changes in the host and directly run the application it throws a proper error saying ADDRESS not found. Also is there a need to use any enviornment variables in the code?

Comment: That's why I was asking for example code. e.g. just db connection ;)

Comment: in addition the package.json would be helpful to know your dependencies

Comment: The issue isnt the quotes. The issue is with the docker-compose file. You see if takes the reference of testorganization and hence the Dockerfile doesnt run. Removing `image:testorganization` worked. Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer, please accept it if it reflects the Solution

Comment: Thank you so much!! i had the same error with mysql.